# Passover obligations

Tags: halacha, passover, maseches-pesachim

https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.43b.2 Brings down women are obligated in matzah eating by Torah law due to the fact they are prohibited in chametz eating, are minors under bar/bat mitzvah age by biblical Halacha prohibited from chametz to the extent they are obligated in matzah eating, and if so is it a mitzvah to donate matzah to say a Jewish orphanage?

Comment: They're not personally obligated, but there's an obligation on their parents (or in the case of orphans, the community) to educate and train them in the ways of Torah. It would certainly be a mitzvah to donate matzah to that end.

Comment: "are minors under bar/bat mitzvah age by biblical Halacha prohibited from chametz" The narrow answer is no. Minors are biblically permitted in everything and have no biblical obligations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A childs father has a mitzva of Chinuch of giving him Matza.
One may not feed a child Chametz see Shulchan Aruch OC 343:

קטן אוכל נבילות אין ב"ד מצווין להפרישו אבל אביו מצווה לגעור בו ולהפרישו  (מאיסור דאורייתא)  ולהאכילו בידים אסור אפילו דברים שאסורים מדברי סופרים וכן אסור להרגילו בחילול שבת ומועד ואפי' בדברים שהם משום שבות: הגה וי"א דכל זה בקטן דלא הגיע לחינוך אבל הגיע לחינוך צריכים להפרישו (תוס' פרק כ"כ) וי"א דלא שייך חינוך לבית דין אלא לאב בלבד (ב"י)

A child may eat unkosher meat and the court is not required to prevent him from doing so, but his father must rebuke him and stop him from doing this (Torah prohibition). It is forbidden to actively feed him even foods that are only rabbinically forbidden. Similarly, it is forbidden to allow him to regularly desecrate Shabbat or holidays, even with rabbinically forbidden activities. Rem"a: There are some who limit this to a child who has not reached the age of education, but if he has reached this age, it is necessary to prevent him from sinning (Tosafot Perek Kol Kitvei), and some say that only his father, and not the court, is responsible for the child's education (Beit Yosef).

This is a obligation incumbent on the father (or another adult according to some opinions and that is the accepted halacha by a Biblical prohibition see MB 343). However the child is not commanded to refrain from eating Chametz.

Women however, are forbidden from eating eating chametz biblicaly therefore are required to eat matza (the first night).

Regardless, it would be a big mitzva to donate matza to an orphanage.